# How to set value to all input row

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to set input value to all input row by using JavaScript.
Please help me.

```js
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set Value To All Input</button>

<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
```

This code runs for first input row only. But I need to set value to all input rows.
Any body please help me.

Comment: id is unique , it can not be same. You can give class instead and do document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `class="myText"` instead of `id="myText"` , and use `getElementsByClassName`, or `querySelectorAll` to select the inputs

And then loop trough them

```
function myFunction() { 
        
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myText"); 
            
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
  elements[i].value = "Johnny Bravo" 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't have a duplicate id, id's must be unique. Use a classname instead with getElementsByClassName.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myText");
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].value = "Johnny Bravo"
        }
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set Value To All Input</button>

<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) method as follow,

```js
function myFunction() {
       
       var eles = document.querySelectorAll("#myText");

       for(const el of eles){
          el.value ='Johnny Bravo';
       }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set Value To All Input</button>

<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" id="myText" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also try using querySelectorAll method with direct element. Also, Id should be always unique.
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ELEMENTS = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  for (var elem=0, length=ELEMENTS.length; elem<length; elem++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("myText")[elem].value = 'Johnny Bravo';
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set Value To All Input</button>
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input  type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example you could use `getElementsByClassName` change your imput id's to classes loop through the elements and assign a value to them

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myText");
function myFunction() {
  new Array(inputs.length).fill().forEach((_,i) => {
    inputs[i].value = "Johnny Bravo";
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set Value To All Input</button>

<input type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
<input type="text" name="part_name[]" class="myText" value="" />
```